# как передать Arraylist с помощью MimeMessage

Tags: java, android

Необходимо передать на почту с помощью `MimeMessage` `Arraylist`, в котором находятся экземпляры класса, чтобы в письме выводились данные `Arraylist` в строку заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
List<MimeMessage> msgs....
String json = new GSON().toJson(msgs);
```

В `toJson` передается коллекция, и GSON генерирует JSON строку, например:

```
public class Person {
    public String name = "Max";
}

{"name":"Max"}
```

Comment: не получается gson передать на почту при открытии письма тот arraylist что был записан в gson не выводиться

Comment: @Алексей, там не ArrayList там будет json